# On demand SQL snapshot replication synchronization with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, replication

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to make it easier to perform on-demand synchronizations from our master data server to our test servers.  We are currently using snapshot replication and only synchronize the data between projects so it could be days or weeks before the data needs to be updated.  There are many databases involved and I would like to be able to run a PowerShell script that will update the snapshots, reinitialize the subscriptions and then start the sync process.  I have been doing this with the Replication Monitor but there are many steps and I would like to be able to ensure that everything happens the exact same way each time, hence the script.

All I can find on the subject of SQL Replication and PowerShell is how to script new publications and subscriptions or to monitor currently running replication processes.  There doesn't seem to be anything about actually starting the synchronization process.  Ultimately I'd like to encapsulate this functionality and only have to provide a few parameters like publisher, publication and subscriber.

Does anyone have something they have used to initiate on demand replication with MS SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an old script I wrote to synchronize a Transactional Replication pull subscription.  It's all based on using [RMO to Synchronize a Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/synchronize-data?view=sql-server-ver15).

RMO covers all replication types, so it should work for snapshot with minor changes:

```
$asm = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")
$asm = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication")
$asm = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.RMO")

function Do-Replication
{
<# 
   .SYNOPSIS Initiate Merge Replication Sync .DESCRIPTION This Function kicks of a Transactional Replication Synchronization 
   .EXAMPLE Give an example of how to use it .PARAMETER subscriber The SQL Instance Name name of the Publication, EG localhost 
   .PARAMETER spublisher The SQL Instance Name name of the Publisher, eg MyPublisher .PARAMETER publication The name of the publication 
   .PARAMETER subscriptionDatabase The name of the Subscriber Database .PARAMETER publicationDatabase The name of the publisher database 
   .PARAMETER forceReInit $true to force a ReInitialization of the subscription, $false otherwise .PARAMETER verboseLevel Logging verbosity level 
   .PARAMETER retries Number of times to retry the sync in case of a failure 
   
#>
  param(
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory = $true,position = 0)] $subscriber,
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory = $true,position = 1)] $publisher,
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory = $true,position = 2)] $publication,
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory = $true,position = 3)] $subscriptionDatabase,
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory = $true,position = 4)] $publicationDatabase,
    [Boolean][Parameter(Mandatory = $true,position = 5)] $forceReInit,
    [int32][Parameter(Mandatory = $true,position = 6)] $verboseLevel,
    [int32][Parameter(Mandatory = $true,position = 7)] $retries) 
    
    "Subscriber: $subscriber";
    "Publisher: $publisher";
    "Publication: $publication";
    "Publication Database: $publicationDatabase";
    "Subscription Database: $subscriptionDatabase";
    "ForceReInit: $forceReinit";
    "VerboseLevel: $verboseLevel";
    "Retries: $retries";

    for ($counter = 1; $counter -le $retries; $counter++) 
    { 
      "Subscriber $subscriber";
      $serverConnection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection $subscriber;
      try 
      { 
        $serverConnection.Connect();
        $transPullSubscription = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.TransPullSubscription;
        $transPullSubscription.ConnectionContext = $serverConnection;
        $transPullSubscription.DatabaseName = $subscriptionDatabase;
        $transPullSubscription.PublisherName = $publisher;
        $transPullSubscription.PublicationDBName = $publicationDatabase;
        $transPullSubscription.PublicationName = $publication;
        if ($true -ne $transPullSubscription.LoadProperties()) 
        { 
          throw New-Object System.ApplicationException "A subscription to [$publication] does not exist on [$subscriber]"  
        } 
        if ($null -eq $transPullSubscription.PublisherSecurity) 
        { 
          throw New-Object System.ApplicationException "There is insufficent metadata to synchronize the subscription. Recreate the subscription with the agent job or supply the required agent properties at run time.";
        } 

        $transPullSubscription.SynchronizationAgent.Output = "c:\temp\ReplicationLog.txt";
        $transPullSubscription.SynchronizationAgent.OutputVerboseLevel = $verboseLevel;

        if ($forceReInit -eq $true) 
        { 
          $transPullSubscription.Reinitialize();
        } 

        $transPullSubscription.SynchronizationAgent.Synchronize();
        "Sync Complete";
        return;
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
      if ($counter -lt $retries) 
      { 
          $_.Exception.Message + ": " + $_.Exception.InnerException "Retry $counter"; 
          continue; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
          return $_.Exception.Message + ": " + $_.Exception.InnerException 
      } 
    }
  }

}


Do-Replication -subscriber "DBROWNE0" "DBROWNE0" "inventory" "subscriberTest" "replTest" $false 1 4;
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helps out a lot.  I was able to change it to use push replication instead of pull.  In case anyone searches for how to do this in the future all you need to do is change the TransPullSubscription to be TransSubscription and match up the appropriate publisher/subscriber properties.  Another thing that would need to be set is to include the SynchronizationAgentProcessSecurity.Login & Password properties.

Now all I need to do is figure out how to identify and run the snapshot agent.

Comment: I figured out how to run the snapshot agent.

Use [MySourceDatabase];
GO
sp_startpublication_snapshot 'MyPublicationName';

I was able to incorporate that SQL statement into the PowerShell script provided by David and it is working as I intended.

THANKS!